# Jquery - input data transfer not precise

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have no clue why this code works so badly. Take a look: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ed6rjufv/3/).

While sliders display value properly in the first input, simple mathematical tasks (multiply) calculate wrong number. Why is that?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.variations').after('<form class="sliding_values" id="sliding_values">');
    $('.sliding_values').after('<p><label for="slide_portal">% 1</label><input id="slide_portal" type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" /></p>');
    $('#slide_portal').after('<p><label for="slide_autor">% 2</label><input id="slide_autor" type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" /></p>');
    $('#slide_autor').after('<p><label for="slide_fundacja">% 3</label><input id="slide_fundacja" type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" /></p>');
    $('#slide_fundacja').after('</form>');


    $(function(){
        var currentValue1 = $('input[name="_dla_portalu"]');
        $('#slide_portal').change(function(){
            currentValue1.val(this.value);
        });
        $('#slide_portal').change();

        var currentValue2 = $('input[name="_dla_autora"]');
        $('#slide_autor').change(function(){
            currentValue2.val(this.value);
        });
        $('#slide_autor').change(); 

        var currentValue3 = $('input[name="_dla_fundacji"]');
        $('#slide_fundacja').change(function(){
            currentValue3.val(this.value);
        });
        $('#slide_fundacja').change();              
    });


    $('input').change(function(){
        var amount1a=$('input[name="_dla_autora"]').val();
        var amount2=$('#pa_kategoria-cenowa').val();
        var amount1b=$('input[name="_dla_fundacji"]').val();
        var amount1c=$('input[name="_dla_portalu"]').val();
        var fractal=0.01;
        var Total1=(amount1a*amount2*fractal);
        $('input[name="pln_dla_autora"]').val(Total1);
        var Total2=(amount1b*amount2*fractal);
        $('input[name="pln_dla_fundacji"]').val(Total2);
        var Total3=(amount1c*amount2*fractal);
        $('input[name="pln_dla_portalu"]').val(Total3);     
    });

});
```

Comment: What is the desired behavior?

Comment: just take a look on jsfiddle. It just calculates wrong - e.g. pick from dropdown value 10. when you will use 1st slider to achieve value 100, in the field PLN 1 should appear: 10, and currently output is ridiculous. When you will move slider left the min value is not 1 (as in the code) but sometimes it shows there maximum :|

Comment: Side note: [use English for identifiers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1483/do-people-in-non-english-speaking-countries-code-in-english) (side side note: cześć rodaku).

Comment: yeah i know but coding in PL is one of the demands from my client/friend (side note: hej;))

Comment: Not certain what expected result is ?

Comment: proper calculation between fields & avoiding delay in it.

Comment: Difficult to determine what expected mathematical result should be ? Can create single slider , single input element and describe what result should be mathematically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is caused by sliders' `change` event listeners executing after your input's `change` event listener. Put the input's event listener inside the `$(function() {})` and it should work:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.variations').after('<form class="sliding_values" id="sliding_values">');
  $('.sliding_values').after('<p><label for="slide_portal">% 1</label><input id="slide_portal" type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" /></p>');
  $('#slide_portal').after('<p><label for="slide_autor">% 2</label><input id="slide_autor" type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" /></p>');
  $('#slide_autor').after('<p><label for="slide_fundacja">% 3</label><input id="slide_fundacja" type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" /></p>');
  $('#slide_fundacja').after('</form>');
 

  $(function(){
    var currentValue1 = $('input[name="_dla_portalu"]');
    $('#slide_portal').change(function(){
      currentValue1.val(this.value);
    });
    $('#slide_portal').change();
  
    var currentValue2 = $('input[name="_dla_autora"]');
    $('#slide_autor').change(function(){
        currentValue2.val(this.value);
    });
    $('#slide_autor').change(); 

    var currentValue3 = $('input[name="_dla_fundacji"]');
    $('#slide_fundacja').change(function(){
        currentValue3.val(this.value);
    });
    $('#slide_fundacja').change();   
    $('input').change(function(){
      var amount1a=$('input[name="_dla_autora"]').val();
      var amount2=$('#pa_kategoria-cenowa').val();
      var amount1b=$('input[name="_dla_fundacji"]').val();
      var amount1c=$('input[name="_dla_portalu"]').val();
      var fractal=0.01;
      var Total1=(amount1a*amount2*fractal);
      $('input[name="pln_dla_autora"]').val(Total1);
      var Total2=(amount1b*amount2*fractal);
      $('input[name="pln_dla_fundacji"]').val(Total2);
      var Total3=(amount1c*amount2*fractal);
      $('input[name="pln_dla_portalu"]').val(Total3);  
    }); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="variations">
                   <div class="variations_lines">

                    <div class="value">
 <select id="pa_kategoria-cenowa" name="attribute_pa_kategoria-cenowa">
<option value="">---</option>
<option value="10" class="attached enabled">10.00</option>
<option value="15" class="attached enabled">15.00</option>
<option value="5" class="attached enabled">5.00</option>
</select>                         
   </div><!-- .value -->
</div><!-- .variations_lines -->
</div>
                

<div class="wccpf-fields-group-1"> 
   
  <table class="wccpf_fields_table " cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td class="wccpf_label"><label for="_dla_portalu">% 1</label></td>
     <td class="wccpf_value">
      <input type="number" class="wccpf-field" name="_dla_portalu" value="%" placeholder="" min="50" max="100" step="1">
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  
     
  
   
  <table class="wccpf_fields_table " cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td class="wccpf_label"><label for="_dla_autora">% 2</label></td>
     <td class="wccpf_value">
      <input type="number" class="wccpf-field" name="_dla_autora" value="%" placeholder="" min="0" max="100" step="1">
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  
     
  
   
  <table class="wccpf_fields_table " cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td class="wccpf_label"><label for="_dla_fundacji">% 3</label></td>
     <td class="wccpf_value">
      <input type="number" class="wccpf-field" name="_dla_fundacji" value="%" placeholder="" min="0" max="100" step="1">
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  
     
  
    
  <table class="wccpf_fields_table " cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td class="wccpf_label"><label for="pln_dla_portalu">PLN 1</label></td>
     <td class="wccpf_value">
      <input type="text" class="wccpf-field" name="pln_dla_portalu" value="" placeholder="" maxlength="">
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  
    
  
    
  <table class="wccpf_fields_table " cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td class="wccpf_label"><label for="pln_dla_autora">PLN 2</label></td>
     <td class="wccpf_value">
      <input type="text" class="wccpf-field" name="pln_dla_autora" value="" placeholder="" maxlength="">
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  
    
  
    
  <table class="wccpf_fields_table" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td class="wccpf_label"><label for="pln_dla_fundacji">PLN 3</label></td>
     <td class="wccpf_value">
      <input type="text" class="wccpf-field" name="pln_dla_fundacji" value="" placeholder="" maxlength="">
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  
    
 </div>
```